# Facing weired behaviour in nuxt query object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my search page, by default I am using `page=0` for pagination. And in the `asyncData` method using this parameter to call the api. But somehow the value is being incremented by one.

So this is my url for example,

> http://localhost:3000/search?page=0

And this is `asyncData` code,

```
    async asyncData({query, app, store}) {
        console.log("[Query Object]", query);

        store.commit('APPLY_SEARCH_FILTER', query);
        let { data } = await app.$api.Search.groups(query);

        let groups = data.data.groups;
        let meta = data.data.meta;

        store.commit('STORE_SEARCH_RESULTS', {
            groups: groups,
            meta: meta
        });
    },
```

And the console log for the query object comes like this,
[image]
When the object is not expanded, it looks like this `[Query Object] > {page: "0", "": null}`. And when expanded the value becomes `"1"`.

```
[Query Object] 
{page: "0", "": null}
page
:
"1"
__ob__
:
Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get page
:
ƒ reactiveGetter()
set page
:
ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__
:
Object
```

And it's always incremented by 1 and I can't figure out from where or why.

**Update**

Search submit button:

```
`<button type="submit" @click.prevent="search" class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase btn-Search">Search</button>`
```

Component state:

```
    data() {
        return {
            search_fields: {
                group_title: null,
                page_test: "abcd"
            }
        }
    },
```

`search()` method

```
search() {
    console.log("[BEFORE EMIT]", this.search_fields);

    this.$store.commit('EMPTY_SEARCH_FILTERS');
    this.$emit('searchClicked', this.search_fields);
 },
```

and the `[BEFORE EMIT]` console log comes like this:
[image]

I can't figure out where the `page' key is being added in the data. I am not adding it in the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the behaviour is expected. You `store.commit` calls, which I suppose leads to the call of the store.mutations, which in turn increment page number by one. Since the javascript values is passed by references and console.log do not actually log item until you press `>` arrow, so at the moment when you press `>` the query object is updated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Yes, the object is being updated in the mutation. But it added another problem. I've updated the question. can you have another look at it?

Comment: the issue is fixed now. the object was being updated somewhere else. I was directly updating the object retreived from vuex getter and it was updating the root state. Thanks a lot.